# facing problem for reviewing first post

Tags: discussion, review-queues

please look below image

[image]

from today morning when i am clicking on 'Review' then I am getting above results of reviewing every time and when i click on the link for reviewing then there is no item there every time as below image

[image]

so i want to know what happen today that this problem only I am facing or other also facing this problem if other also facing this  problem then how to resolve this or we have some problem in our Pc setting ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things that can cause this:

- Caching. This data could be cached for a short time.
- The posts to review are already reviewed when you request them; First Posts get reviewed very quickly.

Comment: yes i know that but i am refreshing page in fraction of seconds then also same problem and i have 1 MB/S line

Comment: @ImranAliKhan If you refresh the page, what do you see? Do you still see the wrong number? Then that could be caused by caching.